# Renci.SSHNet and HP ILO 4

Tags: ssh, ilo

I am using [Renci.SSHNet](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/) to connect to HP iLO processors. Generally this works fine and I can connect and run several commands and disconnect.

However, I noticed that a few new servers that use iLO 4 simply don't react to any but the first command sent. When I login using Putty everything works fine, but when using an SSH connection with Renci only the first command sent is recognised whereas the second and further commands do not cause any reaction whatsoever by the iLO processor, not even an error message.

Any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSH interface isn't really meant for scripting, for this the iLO provides an XML interface via HTTPS. You should be able to use any .net http and xml library to talk to it. HP provides example XML and ther are existing API wrappers in other languages you can use as examples.

Comment: I had considered that but all links Google or I find to HP end on a page with this text: "We apologize, we were unable to find the driver description document you requested." That's why I started using SSH which worked perfectly (especially sinds commands can be tested interactively) until I hit ILO 4.

Comment: ooh, HP have changed their site and it's made of even more suck now, all my old links are broken. If you feel like putting in some effort, you can try my [python-hpilo](https://seveas.github.com/python-hpilo) library/cli and look at the XML it generates.

Comment: Problem is the XML needs hponcfg.exe. hponcfg.exe needs two DLLs that come with the Proliant support pack. The Proliant support pack (difficult to find because of broken links and non-functioning download pages) won't install because it is missing Proliant Management Controller Driver which won't install in a VM. My script server is a VM.

Comment: Turns out hponcfg.exe is for local access. hpqlocfg is for remote access. All links were dead. But I found cpqloccfg which appears to be the older version...

Comment: xml doesn't need hponcfg.exe/cpqlocfg.exe, any old http library (even curl!) can do this.

Comment: Will try this out Monday. Do I just throw the XML at the RIB processor then?

Comment: For ilo/ilo2: yeah, throw it at port 443 on the iLO ip. For ilo3/ilo4 you need to add an HTTP header.